# Implement C++ bitvector in ios project in xcode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, bitvector

I am wondering what the proper way to implement a bitVector in an iOS project is using xcode.

I am pretty new with iOS and just found out I could use the C++ bitvector in my project.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to implement a bit vector data structure or do you want one that already exists?

Comment: I would rather use one that exists as opposed to implementing my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename **C++ bitvector**  project class `.m` files as `.mm` and add it to Xcode.

Watch a sample video tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gngZCdMbdcw)

See a sample code tutorial [here](http://neilmonday.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-compile-basic-c-programs-in.html)

See one good Wrapping C++ tutorial [here](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-1-486)

Comment: ok, and then do I import something? how do I create the bitVector?

Comment: yup.. import the header files to your class.I have edited answer with tutorial links . plz check the links

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" choices for bit vectors in C++ are, in order of decreasing preference:

- `std::bitset` for when you know the number of bits at compile time ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/))
- `boost::dynamic_bitset` for when you don't know the number of bits until runtime or need to change the number of bits dynamically ([documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html))
- `std::vector<bool>` is similar to `boost::dynamic_bitset` but less preferable. Search google for "std::vector" and you will find much discussion on why it is unfortunate. ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/))